# dynamicaly adding list item and links using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have javascript function that adds list items in html list and it works correctly. What i want is to add a link with every link item that is added dynamically. This is the code i have:

```
$.ajax({
    url: uri1 + "?region=" + regionForSearch,
    method: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      region: regionForSearch
    }
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
    var urifordelete = ""

    $('#factories').empty();
    $.each(data, function(key, item) {
      // I want to add code here
      $('<li>', {
        text: formatItem(item)
      }).appendTo($('#factories'));
    });

    iscrtajMapu(data);
  });
```

What i want is to add link in every list item, link should be created like this:

```
var urlForLink = 'http://localhost:50758/api/factories/' + item.ID;
```

I am new with javascript and html. Every suggestion appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

This is what I have now:

[image]

Link leads to deleting item, so I wanted to have information that are plain text and right next to the info, link that says delete and leads to deleting like my data leads to that action now.

Comment: Try to don't use url and use relative path. If something change it will not work

Comment: @Alexis thanks for advice. This project is just for practice it wont be used anywhere.

Comment: May I now why am I getting downs on this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can first append an `<a>` to the `<li>`, and then append that `<li>` to `#factories`. Here's the breakdown of the operations:

```
var li = $('<li>');
var a = $('<a>').attr('href', urlForLink).text(formatItem(item));
li.append(a);
li.appendTo('#factories');
```

Or you can do it in one line like (broken-up for readability):

```
$('#factories')
  .append( 
    $('<li>')
      .append( 
        $('<a>')
        .attr('href', urlForLink)
        .text(formatItem(item))
      )
    )
```

**EDIT based on your update**

Just add the text to `<li>` instead of `<a>`

```
$('#factories')
  .append( 
    $('<li>')
      .text(formatItem(item))    // <--- add text here
      .append( 
        $('<a>')
        .attr('href', urlForLink)
        .text('Delete')          // <--- add text to delete here
      )
    )
```

---

Comment: Hi thank you for the answer. I wanted a link to be next to info, now the text is link. I want to get something like this: data data data link, situation at the moment is that data data data is underlined as link. I am trying to put here a screenshot but i can't atm

Comment: Nema na cemu :). You wanted to get something like what? Can you make a jsfiddle?

Comment: Yes it is. Hvala puno!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at jQuery's [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/).

You can do:

```
$('#factories').append('<li><a href="' + urlForLink + '">' + formatItem(item) + '</a></li>');
```